# Using subprocess to run a Python script with shell=True

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess, resources

I have a Python script `foo.py` that I want to invoke with a second Python script using the `subprocess` module. The code in `foo.py` is provided by a user, and it could be malicious. I have set some security features in place (e.g., resource limits, change UID) prior to running the code to minimize the damage that the user can do.

I'd like to invoke the script with `shell=True` kwarg in the `subprocess.run` command because I am setting resource limits at the UID level. It seems like these limits do not apply if I do not add this kwarg. My code looks something like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

def enable_extra_security() -> None:
  # set a different user ID for security reasons
  os.setuid(1234)

  # limit CPU time usage
  resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (5, 5))

  # limit file size creation 
  resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_FSIZE, (100_000, 100_000))

  # prevent forking
  resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NPROC, (5, 5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # this script is run as root.

  pid = os.fork()

  if pid == 0:
   # child process
   enable_extra_security()
   res = subprocess.run(['/usr/bin/python', 'foo.py'], shell=True, capture_output=True)
   # ...
   # child does some processing based on the returncode and output.
   # ...
  else:
    # parent process
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)

  # ...
  # ...
```

When I invoke `enable_extra_security()`, it only applies the additional security features to the child process. Specifically, the limits are only imposed on user ID 1234, which is only set for the child process. If I run `subprocess.run` without `shell=True`, the security features vanish. Unfortunately, the code above does not work: the `subprocess.run` command will actually just start a Python console and hang (i.e., it does not seem to pass in "foo.py" as an argument).

Interestingly, the code does work for C and C++ code (if I were to replace `/usr/bin/python` with `/usr/bin/gcc` and instead put a `.c` or `.cpp` file, it would work just fine). Why is this happening, and how can I solve my problem?

Comment: If you set `shell=True` you have to pass the command as string, not as list to `subprocess.run` => `subprocess.run('/usr/bin/python foo.py', shell=True, capture_output=True)`

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why do I have to do that for Python programs but not e.g., C or C++ programs?

Comment: See comments on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess